# Emacs: why does keybinding with M-S-[letter] set mark?

Tags: emacs

I'm experimenting with new bindings for basic movement in Emacs.  Borrowing from [this page](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_useful_user_keybinding.html) and [ErgoEmacs](http://ergoemacs.org/), this remapping works as expected:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-i")   'previous-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-k")   'next-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j")   'backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-l")   'forward-char)
```

But defining a Shift-Alt combination gives an unwanted side-effect.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-I")   'cua-scroll-down)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-K")   'cua-scroll-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-J")   'backward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-L")   'forward-word)
```

Running `describe-key` (<kbd>C-h k</kbd>) shows that the bindings were successful.  And these bindings move point as they should, but for some reason it sets the mark at my original position, and gives me a highlighted region as I move the point.

How do I correct this?

EDIT:
This has something to do with cua-mode.  When I disable cua-mode, the problem disappears.  Unfortunately, disabling cua-mode is not a desirable solution.

EDIT:
This is a bug in Emacs.  It's tracked as bug#11221, title 'cua-mode activates the mark for shifted bindings'. From the discussion on the mailing list, it sounds like there will be a fix to cua-base.el.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed likely triggered by `shift-select-mode`, but it looks like a bug: `shift-select-mode` should pay attention to the fact that the command is bound to a shifted key.  Try to reproduce the problem without using CUA and then please report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Setting shift-select-mode to nil has no effect.  And I am having trouble getting rid of cua.  I turned off cua-mode and redefined scrolling to scroll-up and scroll-down, instead of the cua- versions; is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the [shift selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html). You can disable it by setting `shift-select-mode` to `nil`.